# Export pandas data frame to excel only exports final row?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Hi Im kinda new to Python and I'm writing a script for pulling Twitter API data and exporting it to Excel. I can get the all the tweet and date published data into my data frame (i.e. as many tweets as I put in the count parameter) however when I attempt to export the pandas data frame to excel only the last row of the tweet data is present?
I cant figure out why this is?
any help is hugely appreciated thanks
I've written my code below, please let me know how I should change it if you know what to do?

```
#importing key term and date of tweets from twitter archive then exporting it to excel


client_key = 'x'
client_secret = 'x'

import base64

key_secret = '{}:{}'.format(client_key, client_secret).encode('ascii')
b64_encoded_key = base64.b64encode(key_secret)
b64_encoded_key = b64_encoded_key.decode('ascii')

import requests

base_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/'
auth_url = '{}oauth2/token'.format(base_url)

auth_headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(b64_encoded_key),
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
}

auth_data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
}

auth_resp = requests.post(auth_url, headers=auth_headers, data=auth_data)
auth_resp.status_code

auth_resp.json().keys()

access_token = auth_resp.json()['access_token']

search_headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)
}

search_params = {
    'q': 'Key word',
    'count': 3,
    'start_time' : '2019-1-1',
    'end_time' : '2019-2-1',
    'place.fields' : 'USA',
    'lang' : 'en'
}


search_url = '{}1.1/search/tweets.json'.format(base_url)

search_resp = requests.get(search_url, headers=search_headers, params=search_params)

tweet_data = search_resp.json()



for x in tweet_data['statuses']:

    str = (x['created_at'])
    str1 =(x['text'])
    data = {'Date': [(x['created_at'])], 'Text': [(x['text'])]}
    data.update({'Date': [(x['created_at'])], 'Text': [(x['text'])]})



    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd


    df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)


import openpyxl
import openpyexcel

df_data.to_excel(r'C:/Users/Python/Python Project/Twitter API/Twitter API.xlsx', sheet_name='Data')
```

Comment: `df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)` should not indent here so it can make df_data after the for loop finished.

Answer (score 1):

With line `df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)` you create a new dataframe at each loop iteration, erasing the existing one. Indeed the dataframe you write to excel only contains the data of the last loop iteration.

You must not indent this line and keep it unindented outside of the for loop.